# Mute sound in P5JS while still using its waveform?

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I am using the p5.sound library to create an audio visualiser. This works perfectly, however I would like to be able to keep this functionality without the song actually playing.

The waveform and spectrum are both based off of the volume, so setting that to zero means that the whole thing just displays no sound. Is there a way to mute the tab using javascript, or stop the noise from actually playing, just keep it being read by the `.waveform` and `.analyse` functions?

Code: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/523860#code

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve], or a link to a CodePen or your code running in the P5.js web editor?

Comment: I have added the link to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same need, and actually solved with no code, simply muting the tab in the browser.
--> To mute a browser tab in Firefox, right-click the tab and select “Mute Tab”